# Error link url JPATH_SITE in php joomla?

Tags: php, joomla

I have a error:

```
http://www.test.com/downloads/
```

in Joomla I call function

```
$savepath = JPATH_SITE.DS.'downloads';
```

But when put $savepath on tag a is link url become:

```
<a href="<?php echo savepath?>">test</a>
```

=> firebug is url is `test.com/home/test/public_html/downloads/`
How to fix this error to result is:

```
test.com/downloads
```

Or

```
/home/test/public_html/downloads/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this:

```
<a href="<?php echo savepath ?>">test</a>
```

to this:

```
<a href="<?php echo $savepath ?>">test</a>
```

Or you could always use the relative path such as:

```
$savepath = JURI::root() . "/downloads"
<a href="<?php echo $savepath ?>">test</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

`JPATH_SITE` is not your site's URL it's the filesystem path of your installation. Instead use this:

```
$savepath = JUri::root() . 'downloads';
<a href="<?php echo $savepath?>">test</a>
```